# How to avoid If Else statements being skipped if the variable doesn't match the first condition in Batch file

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

This is a batch program that has `If Else` statements and is supposed to change the color of the command prompt when I type a color code. It is supposed to say what it is changing to and then change it. But, for example, I type `0F` it jumps straight to `:INV`. I know `0` is getting set, but `F` never gets set. I believe this is being caused by it going to `:INV` as soon as the program realizes `color_a` or `color_b` doesn't match the first condition for it. If I type `0F`, it would go to `:INV` just because `color_b` isn't `0`. Is there a way to easily fix this in my batch program?

```
@echo off
:SET
cls
echo ----------------------------- Set Colors -----------------------------
echo/
echo --[Colors]--
echo/
echo Set colors.
echo/
pause
:COLORS
cls
echo ----------------------------- Set Colors -----------------------------
echo/
echo --[Colors]--
echo/
echo WARNING: Low contrast colors not recommended.
echo/
echo Set your color. The first digit corresponds to the background; the second the 
echo foreground or characters.
echo/
echo eg. 0F Black backround and bright white foreground
echo/
echo   -Backround-      -Foreground-
echo/
echo    0 = Black       8 = Gray
echo    1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
echo    2 = Green       A = Light Green
echo    3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
echo    4 = Red         C = Light Red
echo    5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
echo    6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
echo    7 = White       F = Bright White
echo/
set /p colors="What color would you like(type the digits in the corresponding order)?"
set color_a=%colors:~0,1%
set color_b=%colors:~-1%
if %color_a%==0 (set color_a_e=black background) else (goto INV)
if %color_a%==1 (set color_a_e=blue background) else (goto INV)
if %color_a%==2 (set color_a_e=green background) else (goto INV)
if %color_a%==3 (set color_a_e=aqua background) else (goto INV)
if %color_a%==4 (set color_a_e=red background) else (goto INV)
if %color_a%==5 (set color_a_e=purple background) else (goto INV)
if %color_a%==6 (set color_a_e=yellow background) else (goto INV)
if %color_a%==7 (set color_a_e=white background) else (goto INV)
if %color_a%==8 (set color_a_e=gray background) else (goto INV)
if %color_a%==9 (set color_a_e=light blue background) else (goto INV)
if %color_a%==A (set color_a_e=light green background) else (goto INV)
if %color_a%==B (set color_a_e=light aqua background) else (goto INV)
if %color_a%==C (set color_a_e=light red background) else (goto INV)
if %color_a%==D (set color_a_e=light purple background) else (goto INV)
if %color_a%==E (set color_a_e=light yellow background) else (goto INV)
if %color_a%==F (set color_a_e=bright white background) else (goto INV)
if %color_b%==0 (set color_b_e=black foreground) else (goto INV)
if %color_b%==1 (set color_b_e=blue foreground) else (goto INV)
if %color_b%==2 (set color_b_e=green foreground) else (goto INV)
if %color_b%==3 (set color_b_e=aqua foreground) else (goto INV)
if %color_b%==4 (set color_b_e=red foreground) else (goto INV)
if %color_b%==5 (set color_b_e=purple foreground) else (goto INV)
if %color_b%==6 (set color_b_e=yellow foreground) else (goto INV)
if %color_b%==7 (set color_b_e=white foreground) else (goto INV)
if %color_b%==8 (set color_b_e=gray foreground) else (goto INV)
if %color_b%==9 (set color_b_e=light blue foreground) else (goto INV)
if %color_b%==A (set color_b_e=light green foreground) else (goto INV)
if %color_b%==B (set color_b_e=light aqua foreground) else (goto INV)
if %color_b%==C (set color_b_e=light red foreground) else (goto INV)
if %color_b%==D (set color_b_e=light purple foreground) else (goto INV)
if %color_b%==E (set color_b_e=light yellow foreground) else (goto INV)
if %color_b%==F (set color_b_e=bright white foreground) else (goto INV)
cls
echo ----------------------------- Set Colors -----------------------------
echo/
echo --[Colors]--
echo/
echo Setting to %color_a_e% and %color_b_e%...
echo/
timeout /t 4 >nul
color %colors%
cls
echo ----------------------------- Set Colors -----------------------------
echo/
echo --[Colors]--
echo/
echo Set to %color_a_e% and %color_b_e%!
echo/
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C YN /M "You wanted these colors correct"
goto Colors

:INV
cls
echo ----------------------------- Set Colors -----------------------------
echo/
echo --[Colors]--
echo/ 
echo Invalid entry, sorry.
echo/
pause
goto COLORS
```

Comment: The key problem is your if else statements fail to consider that any comparison beyond the first will never occur as you skip past them with the first `Else Goto :Inv`. All these if statements can be completeley avoided using choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of using choice within a for loop to capture the literal keypress and avoid unnecessary conditional statements:

```bat
@echo off
Set "c0=Black" & Set "c8=Gray"
Set "c1=Blue"  & Set "c9=Light Blue"
Set "c2=Green" & Set "cA=Light Green"
Set "c3=Aqua"  & Set "cB=Light Aqua"
Set "c4=Red"   & Set "cC=Light Red"
Set "c5=Purple"& Set "cD=Light Purple"
Set "c6=Yellow"& Set "cE=Light Yellow"
Set "c7=White" & Set "cF=Bright White"
Set "da=Background"& Set "db=Foreground"
:COLORS
cls
echo ----------------------------- Set Colors -----------------------------
echo/
echo --[Colors]--
echo/
echo WARNING: Low contrast colors not recommended.
echo/
echo Set your color. The first digit corresponds to the background; the second the 
echo foreground or characters.
echo/
echo eg. 0F Black backround and bright white foreground
echo/
Color /? | findstr /lic:"="
echo/
:ColorPick
 For %%a in (a b)Do (
  Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  Echo( Select !d%%a! Color
  Endlocal
  For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /N /C:0123456789ABCDEF')Do Set "Color_%%a=%%G"
 )
 If "%Color_a%" == "%Color_b%" (
  Echo(Colors must not be the same
  Goto :ColorPick   
 )
cls
echo ----------------------------- Set Colors -----------------------------
echo/
echo --[Colors]--
echo/
Call echo Confirm %%c%color_a%%% and %%c%color_b%%%?
echo/
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C YN /M "You wanted these colors correct"
If not errorlevel 2 (
 color %color_a%%Color_b%
 Echo(Done.
)Else Goto :Colors
Goto :eof
```